# How do I create a shortcut to an application thats already running on the taskbar in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

If I have an application open on the taskbar in windows 7 whats the easiest way of creating a shortcut to that application?

I know that on the desktop you can do Create shortcut and then browse to the application but this seems long winded. Is there a quicker way when I have the app running already?

EDIT: Please note I am trying to create a shortcut somewhere OTHER than the taskbar. e.g. in the start up folder or on the desktop etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

It's not supported by the taskbar API and it won't be possible without 3rd party support.

I tried CTRL+dragging a taskbar program and even tried dragging the right-click shortcut to no avail

But I'm sure John T will come to this topic and post some awesome AutoHotKey script that will create a shortcut to the app which Windows is focused on.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already running the program, simply right click on the icon in the task bar and select "Pin this program to taskbar".

Obviously, this doesn't answer the edited question!

Comment: 2 Seconds. Two bloody seconds. I should maul you.

Comment: @Diago - Post before, to distract them with the "a new answer has been posted" notification, then edit while they are busy checking!

Comment: Darn, I was looking for a dupe before answering... *You fastest gun in the west*

Comment: @Ivo. Don't make me suspend you. You're meant to be moderating. Not answering questions. I am the one on sabbatical.

Comment: Thanks chaps but I am trying to create a shortcut somewhere OTHER than the taskbar.

Comment: HAHAHAHA this is just hilarious... We all answer the wrong question! @Diago, unlike you, I can multitask ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Your stepping on thin ice.